# How to disable SpeechSynthesizer to produce text through speaker

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to generate file with text-to-speech approach.

```
 public AudioResponse GenerateAudio()
{
        _speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = $"{request.Language}-{request.Voice}";
        using SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new(_speechConfig);
      
        SpeechSynthesisResult result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Test");
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\front-doors-opening.mp3", result.AudioData);
        return new AudioResponse { Audio = result.AudioData };
}
```

When **Generate Audio** is executing, file stores and **SpeakTextAsync** plays my text.
Is there any way to configure **SpeechSynthesize** to generate AudioData without producing it?

Packages:

Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech - Version="1.23.0"

.NET 6

Comment: Yeah, I actually using that class, but on SpeakText a hear that text(

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/24ee1373f8ce5996d1ed3f1e36a60d4028537054/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_synthesis_samples.cs#L211

Comment: Yeah it helped, I found there right config TY @HansPassant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help **Hans Passant**, I find right config set up to not produce text generated with **SpeechSynthesizer** through speaker. You just simple need to add config null as **AudioConfig**

```
using var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, null as AudioConfig);
```